# How can I write javascript tests that don't timeout or fail randomly with rspec, capybara, and poltergeist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, bdd, poltergeist

I have been having problems with my tests timing out and failing randomly. I have been looking around for best practices of how to write robust capybara integration tests but I don't find anything helpful.

Ever since we started writing a bunch of tests our CI server has been failing randomly, making our app look ver unstable, but the tests always (mostly) pass locally.

I want to find out how you and other experienced BDD/TDD gurus handle:

- How to deal with external javascript and stuff (KissMetrics, Google Analyics, etc) and
- Debugging and preventing timeout errors that break the build

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which versions of poltergeist and phantomjs are you using? I've encountered seemingly random timing issues with poltergeist > 0.7.0 and phantomjs 1.7.0. They went away when we fixed poltergeist at 0.7.0 and phantomjs < 1.7.0 (I forget which exact number but I think 1.7.0 is when the trouble started).

Comment: I am using poltergeist (1.0.2) and phantomjs 1.7.0. I just noticed that [phantomjs 1.8.9 was released](http://phantomjs.org/release-1.8.html), but I haven't tried that. I will upgrade and test it out. With all of the trouble we have been having I wondered if anyone was using these tools. :)

Comment: Cool. Please report back here with your findings. Curious to know whether my problems might be solved, too. :-)

Comment: I upgraded to phantomjs 1.7.0 to 1.8.1 and nothing changes. I have the latest poltergeist. (I still get timeouts and element not found errors masked as timeouts)

Comment: Nearly 4 years later. This still seems to be a common problem. While these two answers are some of the problem, there still seem to be many other things that can cause random failures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To follow up on this. I appreciated @jonleighton's invitation to file a bug on poltergeist, but the problems that I encountered were related to two separate problems:

1. Bad/wrong capybara assertions that would timeout because I was not following the suggestions clearly outlined in [this post](http://www.elabs.se/blog/53-why-wait_until-was-removed-from-capybara)
2. 3rd party javascripts and things. Basically I had 3rd party javascripts like kissmetrics, google analytics, and even live help chat that would load each time a test was wrong, I eliminated this from happening and my tests got faster and appear to be more stable/consistent.

Comment: This doesn't explain exactly what was the cause of it. Something in the 3rd party scripts was causing it, do you have any clue?

Comment: @joaomilho the problems that I was encountering were related to timeouts and bad assertions in the test, specifically replacing `page.should_not have_content('blah')` with `page.should have_no_content('blah')`

Answer (score 3):

I have found that in many cases I can help my integration tests be more deterministic by taking advantage of Poltergeist's blacklist feature. In my case, I have blacklisted host names like the following.

```
typekit.net
facebook.net
facebook.com
google.com
google-analytics.com
...
```

The idea is to turn off anything that a) is not really needed for testing and b) could affect the page load completion under the CI environment. I have noticed this helps tremendously. Also, using this PhantomJS option with Poltergeist helps too:

```
phantomjs_options: ['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes']
```

Comment: Phantomjs docs specify using true/false for --ignore-ssl-errors, although yes/no is also supported.